# In Objective-C, How one can forward method to specific super class

Tags: c++, objective-c

All I knew is this:  Objective-c allows us  to forward method invocation to its super class by 
    [super method]
However I want forward the invocation to super.super; Skipping the immediately super class.

In c++ we can easily do these by typecasting ((GrandSuper*)object).method().

Is their any provision to do the same in objective c

Comment: The first question would be why? If you need to do that in ObjC you most likely have a design problem.

Comment: Note that in C++, it's safer to avoid typecasting and use this instead: `object.GrandSuper::method()`

Comment: The best thing to do would be to redesign your object model so you don't have to do this.

Comment: Guys, I know its a design problem. But here,only my supervisor permitted edit the super class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to do this, although it is possible. You probably want to think of a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

Let's assume that you have three classes: `Cat` which inherits from `Mammal` which inherits from `Animal`.

If you are in the method `-[Cat makeNoise]`, you can skip `-[Mammal makeNoise]` and call `-[Animal makeNoise]` like so:

```
-(void) makeNoise;
{
    void(*animalMakeNoiseImp)(id,SEL) = [Animal instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(makeNoise)];
    animalMakeNoiseImp(self, _cmd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I just wanted a quick fix.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to [use `objc_msgSendSuper` directly](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSendSuper), i.e.

```
#include <objc/message.h>
...

struct objc_super theSuper = {self, [GrandSuper class]};
id res = objc_msgSendSuper(&theSuper, @selector(method));
```

Comment: Be careful if the selector returns a struct. You'll need to work out whether to use `objc_msgSendSuper` or `objc_msgSendSuper_stret`, which isn't always straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also just call the super of the super:

```
[[[self super] super]functionOfInterest];
```